# Do tea filter bags filter out vitamins and minerals?

Tags: tea, nutrient-composition, filtering

I'm talking about the classic paper tea bags (sold empty) that you can buy and then put whatever you want in; sometimes different sizes are available for cups vs teapots, etc. Yes, I do realise most "pre-filled" tea bags like Lipton have bags made from roughly the same material, but I don't know if those don't filter out nutrients too.

Comment: Hi Valikojan, there is no worldwide consent on what is an "important nutrient". To make your question answerable, you would have to identify the exact nutrient in which you are interested (or more than one, but the list should be short enough to be answerable). Else your question would have to be closed. We have a bit more info on which questions about nutrition we accept - https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/nutrient-composition/info.

Comment: Well, tea is not food. You don't drink it for his nutritional value.

Comment: I think the word important is incidental to the question and answers.

Comment: Many people drink tea for some sort of health benefit @CandidMoe, antioxidants, etc. Food is defined as any liquid or solid that's consumed for taste or nutritional value, so tea is food.

Comment: There's some sort of cultural barrier here, because (from a UK perspective) I have _no idea_ what " the classic paper tea bags (sold empty) " are

Comment: @rumtscho: Do we really want a separate question like this for every possible nutrient in tea, when all(?) of them can be covered by a single answer?  As GdD says, they're all microscopic, unless there's some kind of tea where you want bits of stuff floating in it, not just what can infuse into the liquid.

Comment: @PeterCordes behind your statement "all of them" must exist an assumption of what is a nutrient and what is not. With all opinions on nutrition out there, there are likely to be people who define "a nutrient" to be something which is macroscopic. Also there probably people who feel nourished by tea because it transfers the energy vibration of the grower's aura, which is also not something covered by GdD's answer. And if you want to say "these definitions are ridiculous, so we don't have to take them into account" - our rules were very carefully crafted around us never having to judge ...

Comment: ... which opinion on nutrition should be considered true, or untrue, or ridiculous. So, in the very restricted cases where we do take nutrition-related questions, we require the OP to commit to a strict definition of what they consider "healthy" or "nutritious" or "a nutrient". This may have the side effect of lots of questions, if they want the info on many chemical species - but I consider it more likely that they don't even know which chemical species they mean, which means that we don't want the question at all.

Comment: @rumtscho I like and am thankful for GdD's answer, but to comply with the rules, I've edited the wording; hope it's OK now

Comment: @rumtscho Peter Cordes is right: "Typical" (for Westerners) teas, e.g. black, peppermint, camomile etc., are clear: *Everything* that is in the infusion is solved. The question which of the solved substances we call nutrients, if any, is therefore irrelevant to the statement that all nutrients in tea are "microscopic", which implies that they permeate paper together with the water they are solved in.

Comment: @Valikojan Thanks for updating. Vitamins are a relatively well-defined group. Minerals are hugely diverse though - which ones are do you care about?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica 1. The statement that "everything in the infusion is solved" is not really true. With many tea making methods that don't involve a paper bag, there is plant matter suspended in the infusion, which gets consumed. 2. Staying with the infused-only stuff: How do you know that, on the microscopic level, paper bag fibres don't have a higher affinity for some type of molecules over others, "catching" them out of the solution? 3. The question is not restricted to typical supermarket teas, and filling one's bags is an argument against it.

Comment: @rumtscho Any and all... Like I said - GdD's answer covers everything I wanted to know, just about. But thanks.

Comment: @Valikojan the point is, we don't allow questions where the interest is in "any and all" - for us this constitutes a so-called "too broad" question. The problem with GdD's answer is that its truth content is basically impossible to determine. If there are a thousand minerals, do you think GdD checked the solubility of all thousand of them? (In reality, there may be more than a thousand that come in question, depending on your definition). Even if GdD is an expert chemist and is certain that there can never exist a mineral that gets held back by a teabag, do you think that the people...

Comment: ... reading the question have a similar high expertise in chemistry (despite being mostly interested in cooking) that they can correctly decide whether it's true or false, and downvote accordingly? The answer GdD gave is one of the worst kind we can get - very comforting, but actually unverifiable.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Nutrients are microscopic, the pores in tea bags are far too large to act as a filter. However, tea bags will absorb a very small amount of liquid, and in that liquid there will nutrients, sugars, colors, volatile compounds and other things in suspension. So, the bag is going to absorb some of the tea, but the amount is negligible.

That doesn't mean that everything will get out of the bag, though. Even though the pores in the material are too big to trap nutrients the material is going to impede water circulation. Also, when the leaves expand they tend to get constricted by the bag, which further reduces flow. If you stir the bag around or squeeze it you'll often see darker water coming out of it, which demonstrates this effect. The upshot is that the material isn't filtering vitamins and minerals, but the slower circulation means some tea is going to be left inside the bag, and therefore nutrients along with it. Stirring the bag around a bit helps to a certain extent.

Comment: Well, some substances like active coal can absorb "microscopic" substances, e.g. toxins. The pore size is a different category than the chemical properties of a filter. A correlation exists because filter materials work best if the fluid to be filtered passes by a lot of surface area on the way through, which is helped by small pores. But the pores can, I think, be much larger than the molecules a chemical filter, e.g. made of charcoal, absorbs.

Comment: Peter makes a very important point here. For a visual demonstration of why your assumption does not hold: Make some hibiscus tea, steeping for maybe two minutes. It will be pink, due to natural dyestuff from the hibiscus that gets dissolved in the water. Now take the teabag out and press it with your fingers (or if you prefer, lay it in a second vessel and cut it, not squeezing out anything extra from the plant). The liquid coming out will be a deep red-pink, much darker than the tea in your mug. The teabag holds back a lot of dye molecules that are dissolved in the water inside it.

Comment: That effect is due to the leaves being compacted in the bag, which restricts water flow @rumtscho. The bag material isn't filtering the dyes, it's just slowing the extraction process. I take your point though, it's worth calling that out, so I'll edit.

Answer (score 2):

Paper filters such as tea bags, exclude at a size of 1 to 1000 microns, nutrient vitamins and minerals in foods and drink are measured in nano sizes for consumptions.  Unless you are dealing with a unique or bulk formulation a paper filter should not limit the  vitamin and mineral passage from one location to another.

Comment: Or, put in other words, filters remove suspended particles. Nutrients, however, are dissolved compounds that cannot be removed mechanically.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica As I mentioned in the comments to the question, the reasoning about all nutrients being dissolved is faulty. When you make tea without a teabag, you also consume plant matter that is suspended, not dissolved, in the water. And the teabag surface has its own chemical properties on a microscopic level. A credible answer would have to consider whether there exists a vitamin that is likely to adhere to paper instead of staying in solution.

Comment: @rumtscho The answer has been rebranded to ask about "vitamins and minerals", and none of these fall into the category of suspended particles. And when you ask the wikipedia for nutrients, you find that it says: "Essential nutrients for animals are the energy sources, some of the amino acids that are combined to create proteins, a subset of fatty acids, vitamins and certain minerals." Again, none of these classify as suspended particles. Finally, teabag fibers are generally cellulose, a polymerized sugar. If that did bind to a nutrient, the nutrient would already be bound within the plant.

Comment: The nutrients themselves aren’t suspended particles — but they may well be (partly or entirely) *carried in* suspended particles, rather than fully dissolved in the water.  So filtering particles can absolutely have the effect of capturing nutrients.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica PLL wrote a great explanation why suspended particles matter. To the second point: the microstructure of cellulose in paper bags is entirely different than the microstructure of cellulose in cells, which changes a lot what stays where. And, imagine a water-soluble molecule X which has a strong affinity for cellulose, but does not form indestructible bonds with it. Some X gets out from the plant matter and is dissolved in the tea. Out of this dissolved X, a lot now clings to the bag, and only very little gets into the tea that is consumed.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica to be clear, I'm not saying that such scenarios are likely. What I'm saying is that it is the responsibility of the answerer to consider whether they are possible, before making sweeping statements. And, if they are possible, it is the answerer's responsibility to demonstrate that they do not occur. Anything else makes the answer useless, due to the danger of faulty premises.

Comment: @rumtscho Yet, there is also the possible mistake of not being clear enough out of fear of not being 100% precise. As long as I do not have any reason to believe that something may be relevant, my working hypothesis must assume that it is not. There is no reason to believe that cellulose from tea bags interacts any different with the compounds in the tea than the cellulose within the tea leaves themselves. And I shave with Occam's Razor.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica It's pretty much certain that cellulose from tea bags interacts differently with the compounds than cellulose from the plant cells, for pretty much the same reason that cellulose in bramble thorns through which I run interacts differently with my sweater than cellulose from the papers on my desk on which I lean my elbows. Only it happens on the microscopic level. When we talk about physical effects, structure is the major factor, and should always be considered.

Comment: @rumtscho Now, that's quite a different vibe from "to be clear, I'm not saying that such scenarios are likely". When I drink a tea, it's a clear liquid, i.e. by and large a solution. Irrespective of whether I use a tea bag or not. As such, there are no considerable amounts of particles present that could contain nutritients. (Since particles would contain nutritients in similar ratios as the original leaves, you'd need to ingest substantial amounts for the nutritients to be relevant.) What gets into the tea, gets into solution. And to this the physical cellulose structure is irrelevant.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica your explanation contains assumptions without any solid evidence ."You'd need to ingest substantial amounts for the nutrients to be relevant" and "the physical structure of cellulose is irrelevant" are both strong claims, for which you would have to show empirical evidence before they become believable.

Comment: @rumtscho The statement about ingesting substantial amounts was immediately followed by parentheses containing it's justification. Likewise, my earlier comments already established that all nutrients are chemical compounds, not particles. As such, those nutrients are either in solution, or still within the tea leaves. Now, compounds in solution are molecules or ions swimming in water, way too small to be impressed by the mechanical structure of cellulose fibers. These are not assumptions without evidence.

Comment: @rumtscho By the way, where is evidence that there actually is a nutrient binding effect that is to be considered? May I remind you, that it is your responsibility of providing evidence if you claim an effect to exist, not my responsibility to disprove it? If you want to assert an effect, you have to supply the evidence to get past Occam's Razor. Until you do, I shave with it.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica we live in a world where, when two items touch each other, they interact. Your theory requires them to interact in a certain way - such that the concentration of vitamins remains unchanged - which is more specific than stating that they can interact in either this specific way, or in other possible ways. So, by Occam's Razor, it is your theory that is more complex than an agnostic theory, and thus should provide evidence. And by that I mean empirical evidence. What you wrote in the parentheses is reasoning that starts from unproven claims.

Comment: @rumtscho I'm claiming nothing that is not basic school knowledge about chemistry. Please stop suggesting I am. And that is the last thing I'm going to say here.